# How to make my profile picture in Facebook private that can't be commented and liked by my friends?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-privacy, facebook-account

I don't want to anyone (including friends) able to liked or comment on my profile picture. Only just view it. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Change the privacy mode to *Only Me***.

To do that, click on your photo in profile page. Then change the privacy mode. It will allow visitors to view your photo but they can't like or comment. This is when you are accessing the [basic mobile version](https://mbasic.facebook.com).

When you are the [responsive mobile version](https://m.facebook.com), follow above steps except there you will something called "More Options". Click on More Options -> Edit Photo -> Audience. Choose *Only Me*.

I haven't checked, desktop version wouldn't be much different.